# Wrong php file everytime i try to access index.php.error 404

Tags: php, xampp

http://localhost/myloginsql/index.php this is what i want but every time i try to access it it gives me this
http://localhost/myloginsql/error.php (error 404 object not found)
I deleted the error.php file a while ago in my ht docs. I don't know whats up

Comment: I think we will need a little more information to help you out. What does the folder structure in your ht docs folder look like? Is there a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess file present?

Comment: no there isn't...C:\xampp\htdocs\Registration\index.php

Comment: So if there is no rewriting of the url through the htaccess file then i don't understand why you expect that when you are navigating to http://localhost/myloginsql/index.php that it will open the file on the \Registration\index.php. Does the URL http://localhost/Registration/index.php work perhaps? If not could you prehaps provide some more information?